# Creating a check box and donation field for paypal

Tags: checkbox, paypal, field

so I am struggling creating a unique paypal field. I do not even know if this is feasible.

I need something that the user can check boxes to buy items, and then add a donation at the end in an empty field, and **then** checkout?

So for example, something like this?

1. 180 USD
2. 35 USD

Enter Donation?  ***_***

Checkout Button

Is this possible?
Thanks!
A

Answer (score 0):

You can try a button like this but neither field is optional:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="E-mail address">

        <!-- Begin First Item -->
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item A">
<input type="radio" name="amount_1" value="male">1.00<br>
<input type="radio" name="amount_1" value="female">2.00<br>
        <!-- End First Item -->

        <!-- Begin Second Item -->
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Test Item B">
<input type="text" name="amount_2" value="5.00"><br>
        <!-- End Second Item -->

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_SM.gif" border="0" name="upload" 

alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" width="87" height="23">
</form>
```

With some development other than just an HTML form it would be possible to make it calculate the item total on your site and then have an optional text field. StackOverflow isn't for getting scripts built for you, it's a development assistance board.